# Second activity loop after CountDownTimer finished

Tags: android, android-intent, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer in my activity.

When the user answer corrects, it will load same activity carrying the remaining time.

But when the countdown finished, the second activity load in loops.

Here is my code for ArcadeActivty:

```
public class ArcadeActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
ImageView image;
String icon_game;
String[] ar;
String name;
String imge;
String desc;
String clue;
int clue_status=0;
int gid = 0;
int level = 0;
long seconds;
final TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
int coin = 0;
private Button btn_clue;
private Button btn_skip;
private TextView txt_coins;
private View view;
private MediaPlayer mp = null;
private TextView lbl_timer; 
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
long currentTime;
int score;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arcade);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null) {
        currentTime = extras.getLong("timeCode");
        score = extras.getInt("myScore");
    } else {
        currentTime = 180000;   
    }

    startTimer();

    final Button btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    btn_clue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clue);
    btn_skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    lbl_timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_timer);
    final EditText txt_answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);


    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_clue);        

    mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
    mDbHelper.open();



    Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getArcade(); 


    name = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "name");
    imge = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "image");
    clue = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "clue");
    clue_status = Integer.parseInt(Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "clue_status"));
    System.out.println(clue_status);
    level = Integer.parseInt(Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "level_order"));
    desc = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "description");
    gid = Integer.parseInt(Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "_id"));

    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.iamnards.gameapp:drawable/" + imge, null, null);
    img.setImageResource(id);

    //lbl_level.setText("Level "+level);

    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (name.toLowerCase().contains(txt_answer.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) && txt_answer.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                //playSound(R.raw.complete);    
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Perfect! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //load_correct_details(imge,name,desc); 
                mDbHelper.updateArcadeStatus(gid);
                mDbHelper.close();  
                score = score+10;
                Intent i = new Intent(ArcadeActivity.this, ArcadeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("timeCode", currentTime);
                i.putExtra("myScore", score);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                //playSound(R.raw.error);  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Are you serious?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }   
    });

    btn_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ArcadeActivity.this, ArcadeActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("timeCode", currentTime);
            i.putExtra("myScore", score);
            startActivity(i);
        }   
    });

}

void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(currentTime, 1000) {
        // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
        // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
            currentTime = leftTimeInMilliseconds;
            lbl_timer.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                if(currentTime<1717){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIMES UP! "+currentTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ArcadeActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("myScore", score);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
        }

    }.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_arcade, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        mDbHelper.close();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void load_clue(View v){

      //handle the click here
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Clue:");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(clue)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                private TextView txt_coins;

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                }
              });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

  }
```

}

Code for ScoresActivity:

```
public class ScoreActivity extends Activity {

final TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
private TextView lbl_score; 
int score;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    score = extras.getInt("myScore");

    lbl_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_score);
    final EditText txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name_score);
    final Button btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

    lbl_score.setText("Your score is: "+score);

    mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
    mDbHelper.open();

     btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isEmpty(txt_name)){
                if(isEmpty(txt_name)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name must not empty. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else { 



                mDbHelper.insertScore(txt_name.getText().toString(), score);
                mDbHelper.close();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ScoresActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            }
         }
     });
}


private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
    return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_arcade, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        mDbHelper.close();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem you are facing

Comment: after the countdown timer finish, ScoreActivity load in loops

Comment: can you edit your post and point what code belongs to ScoreActivity and ArcadeActivity

Comment: I posted the codes for ScoreActivity and ArcadeActivity

Answer (score 0):

You have started your timer but not stopping it. Once your timer is up you need to  cancel your countdown. Add an else part inside onFinish()

```
void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(currentTime, 1000) {
        // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
        // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
            currentTime = leftTimeInMilliseconds;
            lbl_timer.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                if(currentTime<1717){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIMES UP! "+currentTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ArcadeActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("myScore", score);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else{
                  //Added else block
                  this.cancel();

                }

        }

    }.start();

}
```

**Haven't tested it. But you get what the problem is.**